# CoderException: java.io.EOFException when performing GroupByKey on Json values encoded with a CustomCoder using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, google-cloud-dataflow

Why do I get this EOFException when I execute the following code?

I have successfully used `GroupByKey` in simpler situations I think what seems to trigger the error is using a custom coder (for Json objects). Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Here's the error:

```
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.CoderException: java.io.EOFException

    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:186)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.testing.TestPipeline.run(TestPipeline.java:106)
    at com.example.dataflow.TestGroupByKeyCustomCoder.testPipeline(TestGroupByKeyCustomCoder.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.CoderException: java.io.EOFException
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.BigEndianLongCoder.decode(BigEndianLongCoder.java:62)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.InstantCoder.decode(InstantCoder.java:83)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.WindowedValue$FullWindowedValueCoder.decode(WindowedValue.java:621)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.WindowedValue$FullWindowedValueCoder.decode(WindowedValue.java:553)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.KvCoder.decode(KvCoder.java:98)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.KvCoder.decode(KvCoder.java:42)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.CoderUtils.decodeFromSafeStream(CoderUtils.java:157)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.CoderUtils.decodeFromByteArray(CoderUtils.java:140)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.CoderUtils.decodeFromByteArray(CoderUtils.java:134)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.MutationDetectors$CodedValueMutationDetector.<init>(MutationDetectors.java:107)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.MutationDetectors.forValueWithCoder(MutationDetectors.java:44)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readLong(DataInputStream.java:416)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.BigEndianLongCoder.decode(BigEndianLongCoder.java:58)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.InstantCoder.decode(InstantCoder.java:83)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.WindowedValue$FullWindowedValueCoder.decode(WindowedValue.java:621)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.WindowedValue$FullWindowedValueCoder.decode(WindowedValue.java:553)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.KvCoder.decode(KvCoder.java:98)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.KvCoder.decode(KvCoder.java:42)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.CoderUtils.decodeFromSafeStream(CoderUtils.java:157)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.CoderUtils.decodeFromByteArray(CoderUtils.java:140)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.CoderUtils.decodeFromByteArray(CoderUtils.java:134)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.MutationDetectors$CodedValueMutationDetector.<init>(MutationDetectors.java:107)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.MutationDetectors.forValueWithCoder(MutationDetectors.java:44)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.ParDo$ImmutabilityCheckingOutputManager.output(ParDo.java:1303)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:287)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunnerBase.java:449)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.ReifyTimestampAndWindowsDoFn.processElement(ReifyTimestampAndWindowsDoFn.java:38)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:49)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase.processElement(DoFnRunnerBase.java:138)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.ParDo.evaluateHelper(ParDo.java:1229)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.ParDo.evaluateSingleHelper(ParDo.java:1098)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.ParDo.access$300(ParDo.java:457)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.ParDo$1.evaluate(ParDo.java:1084)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.ParDo$1.evaluate(ParDo.java:1079)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DirectPipelineRunner$Evaluator.visitTransform(DirectPipelineRunner.java:858)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.TransformTreeNode.visit(TransformTreeNode.java:219)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.TransformTreeNode.visit(TransformTreeNode.java:215)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.TransformTreeNode.visit(TransformTreeNode.java:215)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.TransformTreeNode.visit(TransformTreeNode.java:215)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:102)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.traverseTopologically(Pipeline.java:259)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DirectPipelineRunner$Evaluator.run(DirectPipelineRunner.java:814)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DirectPipelineRunner.run(DirectPipelineRunner.java:526)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DirectPipelineRunner.run(DirectPipelineRunner.java:96)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:180)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.testing.TestPipeline.run(TestPipeline.java:106)
    at com.example.dataflow.TestGroupByKeyCustomCoder.testPipeline(TestGroupByKeyCustomCoder.java:85)
```

Here is the code:

```
package com.example.dataflow;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.CustomCoder;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.testing.CoderProperties;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.testing.TestPipeline;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.*;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.windowing.GlobalWindow;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.windowing.PaneInfo;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.WindowedValue;
import org.joda.time.Instant;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;


class ParseJson extends DoFn<String, JsonNode> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private transient ObjectMapper om;

    { init(); }

    private void init() {
        om = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        init();
    }

    @Override
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
        JsonNode node = om.readTree(c.element());
        c.output(node);
    }
}

class JsonNodeCoder extends CustomCoder<JsonNode> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    private static final JsonNodeCoder INSTANCE = new JsonNodeCoder();

    public static JsonNodeCoder of() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public void encode(JsonNode value, OutputStream outStream, Context context) throws IOException {
        mapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_TARGET, false).writeValue(outStream, value);
    }

    @Override
    public JsonNode decode(InputStream inStream, Context context) throws IOException {
        return mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_SOURCE, false).readTree(inStream);
    }
}

public class TestGroupByKeyCustomCoder {

    @Test // original code the produces the error
    public void testPipeline() throws IOException {

        TestPipeline p = TestPipeline.create();

        p.getCoderRegistry().registerCoder(JsonNode.class, JsonNodeCoder.class);

        p.apply(Create.of("{}"))
                .apply(ParDo.of(new ParseJson()))
                .apply(WithKeys.of("foo"))
                .apply("GroupByAction", GroupByKey.create());

        p.run();
    }

    // Test as per Kenn Knowles' suggestion
    // this throws the same error
    @Test
    public void testCustomCoder() throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode value = mapper.readTree("{}");

        WindowedValue.FullWindowedValueCoder<JsonNode> windowedValueCoder
                = WindowedValue.FullWindowedValueCoder
                    .of(JsonNodeCoder.of(), GlobalWindow.Coder.INSTANCE);

        WindowedValue<JsonNode> x = WindowedValue.of(
                value, Instant.now(), GlobalWindow.INSTANCE, PaneInfo.ON_TIME_AND_ONLY_FIRING);
        CoderProperties.coderDecodeEncodeEqual(windowedValueCoder, x);
    }
}
```

This issue seems to be caused by readTree consuming too much input, consequently swallowing the timestamp that Dataflow is looking for:

```
@Test
public void testJackson() throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream("{}1".getBytes());
    mapper.readTree(bis);
    Assert.assertNotEquals(bis.read(), -1); // assertion fails
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stack trace indicates that the end of the file is reached when the big endian `long` of the timestamp is being parsed.

The [encoding used by `WindowedValue.FullWindowedValueCoder`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/1f75fa9/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/util/WindowedValue.java#L609) is your encoded value, followed by the timestamp, followed by the windows and finally the pane metadata. So this in turn implies that the `JsonCoder` is consuming too many bytes from the input stream (maybe all of them?) so the decoding of the timestamp hits the end of the file.

The SDK provides a lot of utilities for testing coders in [`CoderProperties`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/testing/CoderProperties.java). You can actually directly test this case, which is in the global window, by running [`CoderProperties#coderDecodeEncodeEqual`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/1f75fa9/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/testing/CoderProperties.java#L102) with a coder `WindowedValue.FullWindowedValueCoder.of(JsonCoder.of(), new GlobalWindow.Coder())`.

There is a flag passed to `encode` and `decode` that you'll probably have to be aware of: the `Coder.Context`.

- `Coder.Context.OUTER` indicates that your coder is the outermost `Coder` and owns the whole stream. In this case, on encoding you can leverage the EOF signal and leave out metadata such as a length-prefix or parentheses, and on decoding it is fine to consume as much as you like.
- `Coder.Context.NESTED` indicates that your `Coder` is encoding just a part of the value, so it needs to write enough metadata that it can intelligently consume just the bytes from its own encoding.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @KennKnowles . I tried creating a test as you described and added it to the above code. It does produce the same error. I dug a bit deeper and found that `ObjectMapper.readTree()` ignores and discards any input that follows a valid JSON document. Is it standard practice to have every dataflow coder to write the length of its output when encoding so the decoder knows where to stop?

Comment: When encoding in a nested context, you will, indeed, need to manage this. That is why many I've added a description of this to the answer. If you take a look at ByteArrayCoder, you can see that it leaves off the length-prefix if the context is the whole stream.

Comment: @KennKnowles Coder context has been deprecated. I am facing this same issue. Anything that I'm missing?